# vba powerpoint 2007 insert picture from url

Tags: vba, powerpoint

this code works well on VBA powerpoint 2013

but when I try to use it in office 2007 I get error

Picture_URL = "https://msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC820563.png"

l = 0: t= 0 : w = 100 : l = 100

Set oPic = ppPres.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture(Picture_URL, False, True, l, t, w, h)

what's wrong? I checked the function AddPictureand found it in office12 library

Comment: [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198302.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  says `Shapes.AddPicture` method is for office 2013 and later.

Comment: @newguy:  Don't be misled by Microsoft's lame documentation. It's often incomplete, misleading or just plain wrong.  As it is here.  Shapes.AddPicture is part of the PPT OM at least as far back as Office 2000 and I'd lay good odds that it's in PPT 97 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/downloading-an-image-from-internet-using-vba/f390d953-9b1a-40c5-bb52-3bad14074943
But I have to remove the outline each time :)